# How can use net/ssh gem to know if a package was installed?

Tags: ssh, grep, dpkg, net-ssh, test-kitchen

I am trying to use the net/ssh gem to find an installed package into my Test-Kitchen instance. I do a simple recipe that reuse the build-essential cookbook.

It is my recipe:

```
node['my-cookbook']['packages'].each do |pkg|
  package pkg
end
```

And these are my attributes:

```ruby
default['my-cookbook']['packages'] = %w[build-essential git bison]
```

These are some steps into my feature definition for cucumber.

```ruby
When(/^I ask for (.*)$/) do |package|

  Net::SSH.start(@infrastructure['my-app'].ip,'vagrant', password: 'vagrant') do |ssh|
    @out = ssh.exec!("dpkg --get-selections | grep #{package}")
  end
end

Then(/^I should see (.*)$/) do |package_respond|
  puts @out
  @out.should match package_respond
end
```

When the instance converge, build-essential was installed and the cucumber test was succesful.

The output

```
puts @out
```

Was

```
grep: build-essential: No such file or directory
```

The test was succesful because the expresion matched. I was expecting

```ssh
build-essential             install
```

What happened here?? 
When a package is not installed the console respond with an empty string.

How can I inspect if an specific package was installed into my kitchen instance using the net/ssh gem?

My kithen instance is ubuntu 12.04.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to use Net::SSH? Why not use a busser like serverspec or bats. Please format your code as well.

Comment: And how can I use serverspec inside cucumber ??

Comment: You don't. Don't use Cucumber...

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing there's a space in some of the packages, or something of the likes.

If that's the case, `build-essential` would come as the second argument of grep, and in that case, grep would try to open it as a file, which of course doesn't exist.

So I would recommend:

`@out = ssh.exec!("dpkg --get-selections | grep \"#{package}\"")`